# TypeError: getItems[props.action] is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm new to react testing, i'm trying to verify react functional component to be there, with this code, but for some reason it is complaining about something else TypeError: getItems [ props.action ] is not a function

any help/suggestion with this, to verify component to be there ?

```js
interface SelectionListProps {
  actionArgs?: string | undefined;
  action: string;
  name?: string;
  identifier?: string;
  classes: {
    button_basic: string;
    formControl: string;
    selectionCard: string;
  };
}

export const SelectionList: React.FC<SelectionListProps> = (
  props
) => {
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const getItems = {
    analysers: (site: any) => dispatch(getAnalysers(site)),
    sites: (site: any) => dispatch(getSites()),
  } as any;

  const initializeCollapses = () => {
  
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems[props.action](props.actionArgs).then(() => {
      initializeCollapses();
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <List component="div" data-testid="SelectionListt">
    </List>
  );
};
```

my testing code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { expect } from "@jest/globals";
import { render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { SelectionList } from "../SelectionList";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../redux/store";

import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

function handleUpdateClick(event: any, type = "") {}
test("test", () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SelectionList
        classes={{ button_basic: "", formControl: "", selectionCard: "" }}
        action={""}
        actionArgs={""}
     
      />
    </Provider>
  );
  const SelectionCardElement = screen.getByTestId("SelectionListt");
  expect(SelectionCardElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an empty string for the `action` name, but `getItems[""]` does not match to any function since the value of `getItems` is:

```
const getItems = {
    analysers: (site: any) => dispatch(getAnalysers(site)),
    platforms: (site: any) => dispatch(getPlatforms(site)),
    brokers: (site: any) => dispatch(getBrokers(site)),
    cameras: (site: any) => dispatch(getCameras(site)),
    sites: (site: any) => dispatch(getSites()),
}
```

Also all functions of *getItems*, but the last one, expect a *site* argument. However currently you are passing an empty string as well for the arguments. In the `sites` function you can remove the unused *sites* argument

Comment: now its working thanks, one thing why am i getting this : Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'Matchers<HTMLElement>'.ts(2339)

Comment: I've seen this type error in the past. The property actually exists on `expect` but is not known in type declarations, if that makes sense. I think it is taken care of by `import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'` but I see you have it. Could it be that it comes from another test file?

Comment: i got it last week and fixed it with this:import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'   but now i renamed my components name from SelectionCard to SelectionList, then got this... and that import is not working anymore

Comment: Ha, I think it might be because you imported expect separately. Try removing the line `import { expect } from "@jest/globals";`

Comment: that is not needed at all there ?

Comment: No because it is covered by `import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";`, which has a version of expect extended with some convenient methods as `toBeInTheDocument`

Comment: yes, its working now !

Comment: yeah, forgot it

Comment: could you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761575/test-what-happens-when-dropdown-is-clicked